# How to set color of SKSpriteNode with image texture?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm working with an SKSpriteNode. My goal is to apply an image texture to the SKSpriteNode and use the spriteNode.color property to change the color of the image.

```
SKTexture *texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:instrument.buttonImageFile];  
self.textureNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture];  
self.textureNode.color = [UIColor redColor];  
self.textureNode.colorBlendFactor = 1.0f;
```

Currently only the image is in view and no coloring of the image occurs. The image is here: [image](http://postimg.org/image/579zqhxt5/). I've looked at a lot of material but seem to either find answers regarding changing the colorBlendFactor (which has given me no luck) or about colorization through SKActions which likewise doesn't apply.

Comment: Keep in mind anything black does not change color. It will remain black. Also I don't see the image.

Comment: I just attached my image and @EpicByte, thanks for pointing that out about black images. My image is indeed black, and that's been the source of my struggle.

Answer (score 6):

Your code totally works in my end. I used the [spritekit spaceship](https://www.google.com/search?q=spritekit%20spaceship&espv=2&biw=1218&bih=678&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=AU6TVerfH8OtyASKoJm4Dg&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAg) and it worked.

```
SKSpriteNode *sprite;

SKTexture *texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];
sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture];
sprite.color = [UIColor redColor];
sprite.colorBlendFactor = 1.0f;
```

My idea is that sometime for some images that even there is color blended, the visual difference is not that obvious. Therefore, I humbly suggest if it is allow, make your images all white and see if color blending makes difference.

Comment: Could you attach the image again. I don't see it know. Last time I saw the image was mostly black and also has a part that is white. I would make the image into two textures and make them both white and loaded into skspritenode. Then I could use colorblending seperately to turn them to the color you need.